# Is it possible to add a name input locating box in "more Stack Exchange communities" and "your communities"?

Tags: feature-request

There has already been a post, *[“More Stack Exchange Communities” Search Improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251220/more-stack-exchange-communities-search-improvement)*.

However, there is not any reply. It might be difficult to be implemented. Whereas, it does not need to be so complex. Is there a name locating input box or name filter which allow the user just input a few letters of the beginning of the name of site and the target site will show up?

It will save a lot of time. Because when I trying to locate a site, even if I know the exact name of it, I have to scroll for a long time, not only a lot of time wasted, but also my good mood destroyed. Could anyone consider the possibility of adding this feature?

Comment: You didn't even try. Basic common sense: before asking for a feature, just try and see if it exists. In this case it's as simple as going to the text box and, well, typing "few letter of the beginning of the name of site".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't this feature already exist? Open the site switcher on the right and you'll see something like this:

[image]

Simply put the name of the site in the red-freehand-circled box and it will filter the list. I haven't had a problem finding sites even with only the first three or so letters of the site name—usually it will be in the top 5 results.